# Excel VBA: Apply predefined cell format after inserting a value

Tags: excel, vba

I use an VBA import script to import data (among others, numbers formatted as strings) into an existing Excel form that already has predefined formatting for the relevant cells (e.g. %). To update, the script simply overwrites the value:

`MyWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Cells(line, column).value = NewValue`

Upon running the script, the cells contain the "unformatted" value (e.g. 0.15). The cell itself however still "knows" its original format and upon manually selecting it and hitting enter, the formatting is applied. (0.15 gets transferred to 15%).
Ironically (?) if I fill the value "0", the cell is automatically, correctly formatted into 0%.

Filling the empty form manually via copy&paste also works perfectly.
How can I simulate this behavior in VBA and insert the value while still applying the sheet's predefined formatting (and still be as efficient as possible)?

Excel version is Excel 2016.

Comment: Where are you getting `NewValue` from? What is its type?

Comment: @BigBen It's a string containing a number, formatted like "0.15". Source is another Excel-File that was exported from SQL.

Comment: That is the problem cell formats do not affect strings.  You need to change `NewValue` to a `Double` before assigning it to the cell.

Comment: ^^^^^^ `MyWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Cells(line, column).value = CDbl(NewValue)`

Comment: @BigBen Most of the original data (90%) to be transferred is actually text, correctly saved as strings, and the input data set is huge and doesn't contain meta information on the type of data. I'd rather not try and convert each string into a double. Is there another option?

Comment: You can use `IsNumeric` to test if the data is numeric... but you *really* should convert your text to actual numbers. Numbers stored as strings are .... problematic, as you're finding out.

Comment: Wouldn't `CDec(NewValue)` be better due to higher precision?

Comment: @BigBen thank you so much - i did the conversion, and efficiency wasn't impacted! - double precision was sufficient.